# CheckBox com CheckBox Externa

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, dropdown

Tenho um Form com Uma DropDownlist com CheckBox dentro, e tenho uma CheckBox externa que seleciona e desmarca todos.

Minha duvida é o seguinte.

Quando desmarco um dos itens no DropDown o CheckBox "Selecionar Todos" deveria ser desmarcado e quando eu selecionasse todos os itens ele deveria ser marcado. Mas quando eu faço os eventos ficam interagindo entre si e ficam dando erro.

Alguém sabe um meio de fazer isso?

Esse é o código do CheckBox Selecionar todos.

```
private void cbSelAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbSelAll.Checked == true)
    {
         //Ao selecionar a flag Selecionar todos marca todos os itens
         for (int i = 0; i < cb.CheckBoxItems.Count; i++)
         {
              cb.CheckBoxItems[i].Checked = true;
         }
    }
    else
    {
        //Ao desmarcar a flag Selecionar todos desmarca todos os itens
        for (int i = 0; i < cb.CheckBoxItems.Count; i++)
        {
            cb.CheckBoxItems[i].Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como tu adicionou `checkbox` dentro da `DropDownlist `?

Comment: Usando um controle chamado CheckBoxComboBox

Comment: seria [este](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and)?

Comment: Sim seria, mas o controle não tem muito a ver com a pergunta, consegui achar a resposta. Eu estava usando o Evento quando o checkbox era marcado então um evento influenciava no outro então eu mudei o evento para click e deu certo :) mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Faça uma flag para saber quando o evento está sendo disparado por outro, e não ser processado:

```
    bool processando = false;
    private void cbSelAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!processando)
        {
            processando = true;

            if (cbSelAll.Checked == true)
            {
                //Ao selecionar a flag Selecionar todos marca todos os itens
                for (int i = 0; i < cb.CheckBoxItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    cb.CheckBoxItems[i].Checked = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Ao desmarcar a flag Selecionar todos desmarca todos os itens
                for (int i = 0; i < cb.CheckBoxItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    cb.CheckBoxItems[i].Checked = false;
                }
            }


            processando = false;
        }

    }
```

Coloque o if:

```
if (!processando)
{
  processando = true;
//Processo
  processando = false;
}
```

dentro dos outros eventos também.

Answer (score -2):

O melhor que achei, mais simples e mais direto foi este:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*
    // MARCA/DESMARCA TODOS OS CHECKBOX DE UMA VEZ
    */
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#todos').click(function() {
            var val = this.checked;
            $('.lista').each(function() {
                $(this).prop('checked', val);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input id="todos" type="checkbox">
                </th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;">ID.</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;">Nome</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;">Localização</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class=" colunaCheck">
                    <input class="lista" value="opcao1" type="checkbox">
                </td>
                <td> 1</td>
                <td>Sophia Sueli Oliveira</td>
                <td>Porto Alegre - RS</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="colunaCheck">
                    <input class="lista" value="opcao2" type="checkbox">
                </td>
                <td> 2</td>
                <td>Nathan Ricardo Costa</td>
                <td>Campo Grande - MS</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="colunaCheck">
                    <input class="lista" value="opcao3" type="checkbox">
                </td>
                <td> 3</td>
                <td>Sérgio Osvaldo Caleb Almada</td>
                <td>Belém - PA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="colunaCheck">
                    <input class="lista" value="opcao4" type="checkbox">
                </td>
                <td> 4</td>
                <td>Enzo Vinicius Paulo da Paz</td>
                <td>Franca - SP</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

É muito simples e intuitivo.
O primeiro Checkbox, aquele que marca/desmarca os demais recebe o `id="todos"` e os que serão marcados/desmarcados o `class="lista"`.